# How to consume messages from Kafka by type

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I'm new to kafka and have some questions about it. I have configured a kafka consumer to consume messages from topic and I'm having different types of events coming to the topic.
f.e.

```
class Event {
    String type;
    Object event;
}
```

I want to configure different kafka listeners to consume different types of events.
I see two ways of doing it like consuming event in String(json) format and the converting to event object and switching between types and doing business logic, or configuring different kafka listener factory

```
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> businessEventStreamListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.setRecordFilterStrategy(consumerRecord -> !consumerRecord.value().contains("typeOfObjectIWantToConsume"));
        return factory;
    }
```

So the first approach is not `SOLID` and for the second one I need to create a lot of factory classes. Is there any way to do this more elegantly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this kind of business requirements was really a reason why we have introduced a `@KafkaHandler`.

See more info in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#class-level-kafkalistener.

Comment: thanks a lot. I managed to do it with KafkaHandlers